# dar provincia a traves del codigo postal

Tags: javascript

por favor tengo este script en mi web y funciona bien, el problema es que quiero solo validar solo los códigos que son correctos. Si le pongo el 99999, también continua.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function darProvincia(cpostal){
        var cp_provincias = {
            1: "\u00C1lava", 2: "Albacete", 3: "Alicante", 4: "Almer\u00EDa", 5: "\u00C1vila",
            6: "Badajoz", 7: "Baleares", 08: "Barcelona", 09: "Burgos", 10: "C\u00E1ceres",
            11: "C\u00E1diz", 12: "Castell\u00F3n", 13: "Ciudad Real", 14: "C\u00F3rdoba", 15: "Coruña",
            16: "Cuenca", 17: "Gerona", 18: "Granada", 19: "Guadalajara", 20: "Guip\u00FAzcoa",
            21: "Huelva", 22: "Huesca", 23: "Ja\u00E9n", 24: "Le\u00F3n", 25: "L\u00E9rida",
            26: "La Rioja", 27: "Lugo", 28: "Madrid", 29: "M\u00E1laga", 30: "Murcia",
            31: "Navarra", 32: "Orense", 33: "Asturias", 34: "Palencia", 35: "Las Palmas",
            36: "Pontevedra", 37: "Salamanca", 38: "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", 39: "Cantabria", 40: "Segovia",
            41: "Sevilla", 42: "Soria", 43: "Tarragona", 44: "Teruel", 45: "Toledo",
            46: "Valencia", 47: "Valladolid", 48: "Vizcaya", 49: "Zamora", 50: "Zaragoza",
            51: "Ceuta", 52: "Melilla"
        };
        if(cpostal.length == 5 && cpostal <= 52999 && cpostal >= 1000){
            document.getElementById('provincia').value = cp_provincias[parseInt(cpostal.substring(0,2))];
        }else{
            document.getElementById('provincia').value = "---";
        }
```

Comment: Pues a mi me funciona bien. Tal como está programado. Me devuelve `---` si le paso 99999. Compruebalo aquí:  https://jsfiddle.net/d4ojtchn/ ... no entiendo cual es el problema aun.

Comment: Puedes crear un [repro] _en_ la pregunta pulsando en el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Lo que necesito es que me devuelva error cuando se indique un código postal erróneo por ejemplo 99999

Comment: necesito que me devuelva un error y no me deje continuar cuando se introduce un codigo postal que no es correcto

Comment: ¿Continuar el que?  Creo que nos falta información. En mi ejemplo anterior me tuve que inventar un botón que lanzara esa función por falta de más contexto. Mírate el enlace sobre el código mínimo verificable que @padaleiana te ha dado y ayúdanos a ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. No me aclaro mucho en este portal. Lo que necesito es que el campo código postal del formulario no deje continuar al usuario si el código postal no es correcto

Comment: Es muy raro esto que quieres hacer en ese input, porque si pongo un codigo postal correcto me lo cambia por el nombre de la provincia... ¿pero si pongo un nombre de provincia que debe pasar? ¿no has pensado en verificar tambien el nombre de la provincia?  Y sigo sin entender que es **continuar** para ti... ¿impedir darle a un boton de Enviar o algo así?  Pon el HTML relacionado si quieres mas ayuda (es decir, donde aparezca el elemento con el id `provincia` y lo que tenga al lado, y si es un formulario entonces ponlo completo.

Comment: ¿O son dos inputs?  Claro, debe ser eso. Bueno, pues lo dicho, pon el HTML para mas ayuda, gracias, no me gusta mirarme las cosas a ciegas.

Comment: a ver si te vale. ,seguramente no me estoy explicando bien. lo que necesito hacer es exactamente esto: https://www.terranea.es/seguro-comunidades/comparador-seguros-oficinas.aspx#

Comment: Disculpame, no se como enviar el formulario o el html. por aquí

Comment: No se envia, se copia el texto y se pega en el editor de la pregunta.  Luego seleccionas todo y le das al botón `{}` para que lo indente y aparezca como código. Al principio cuesta un poco, pero si te fijas, mientras escibes en el editor, vas viendo como queda por debajo de el y te das cuenta de si lo que vas a enviar es correcto o queda fatal.

Comment: @PEDRO: He visto el código de tu web y no habeis sabido aplicar lo que os digo en mi respuesta.  Mirate la parte final de la misma, a partir de aqui:  `if (cpostal.length == 5 ` y veras que vosotros lo haceis de otra forma.  Si poneis lo que os digo yo os deberia funcionar mejor, pues os deshabilitará el boton (que en vuestro caso se llama `paso3Next` y no `enviar` como yo he puesto en mi código de ejemplo.

Comment: he puesto el código y lo he adaptado de varias maneras pero no funciona.  En la caja de texto de codigo postal del formulario tiene este atributo: onkeyup="darProvincia(this.value);"    . en la caja de texto provincia en atributos tiene este texto;  onclick="rsfp_changePage(4, 3, 14, 0, {'parent':'','field':'is-invalid'})" y en el botón abanzar (paso3Next), tiene este código en atributos:    onkeyup="javascript:if(this.value.length == 5 &amp;&amp; !isNaN(this.value)) {darprovincia(this.value.substring(0, 2));}">

Comment: @PEDRO: No se que decirte, tal como ves en el snippet de la respuesta, si lo ejecutas, el código funciona tal y como lo habias pedido en la pregunta.  Lo que ya no puedo saber es porque no funciona en un entorno distinto al preguntado. Y la verdad, no creo que eso deba hacerlo yo, sino más bien tu, basándote en mi respuesta y extrapolar todo lo necesario al entorno que tienes en tu web. Si no te convence mi respuesta deberias cambiar tu pregunta y ver si alguien más te puede ofrecer una solucion en un entorno mas especifico. Ya te dije desde el principio que faltaba informacion.

Comment: @PEDRO: Quizás, si hubieras dicho desde el principio de que se trataba completamente no hubiera invertido un minuto de mi tiempo en mirarmelo por desconocer los formularios RSform Pro que me has comentado antes. Tan solo he pretendido ayudar basándome en una pregunta específica, que pretendia ser simple, pero no trabajar gratis.

Comment: @PEDRO: Además, estoy seguro que mi código funciona si lo miras con detenimiento y lo sabes aplicar a tus elementos correctamente, pues efectivamente llamais a la funcion `darProvincia` por lo tanto el resto esta dentro de la propia funcion. Tan solo fijaros en los nombres de los elementos a ver si coinciden o no.

Comment: No pretendía ocasionarte molestias. Mi falta de experiencia y conocimiento ha sido el culpable. Te agradezco muchisimo la ayuda, Se que tu código funciona, incluso mejor que e mío, pero no veo la forma de adaptarlo. Llevo 3 días con esto y lo volvere a revisar con pacienca. Muchas gracias de verdad y mil discujpas

Comment: No me ha causado molestias hacerlo, basándome en un contexto predefinido concreto. Yo tambien aprendo mientras lo hago y eso me encanta. Pero si luego hay variaciones de ese contexto que no estaban especificados no me puedo sentir responsable de ello. Te recomiendo que vuelvas a preguntarlo con todo el contexto necesario. Si mi respuesta resuelve tu pregunta inicial te recomiendo la aceptes para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede abierta eternamente. Te paso un enlace donde explican como aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200

Answer (score 0):

He hecho una adaptación de tu código basándome en lo que he visto en esa URL que has pasado en los comentarios de la pregunta.

Pruébalo y si te parece bien lo dices y te lo documento un poco para que entiendas los cambios aplicados.

Queda así:

```js
const codigopostal = document.getElementById('codigopostal');

codigopostal.addEventListener('change', darProvincia);

function darProvincia(e) {

  cpostal = e.target.value;

  var cp_provincias = {
    1: "\u00C1lava",
    2: "Albacete",
    3: "Alicante",
    4: "Almer\u00EDa",
    5: "\u00C1vila",
    6: "Badajoz",
    7: "Baleares",
    08: "Barcelona",
    09: "Burgos",
    10: "C\u00E1ceres",
    11: "C\u00E1diz",
    12: "Castell\u00F3n",
    13: "Ciudad Real",
    14: "C\u00F3rdoba",
    15: "Coruña",
    16: "Cuenca",
    17: "Gerona",
    18: "Granada",
    19: "Guadalajara",
    20: "Guip\u00FAzcoa",
    21: "Huelva",
    22: "Huesca",
    23: "Ja\u00E9n",
    24: "Le\u00F3n",
    25: "L\u00E9rida",
    26: "La Rioja",
    27: "Lugo",
    28: "Madrid",
    29: "M\u00E1laga",
    30: "Murcia",
    31: "Navarra",
    32: "Orense",
    33: "Asturias",
    34: "Palencia",
    35: "Las Palmas",
    36: "Pontevedra",
    37: "Salamanca",
    38: "Santa Cruz de Tenerife",
    39: "Cantabria",
    40: "Segovia",
    41: "Sevilla",
    42: "Soria",
    43: "Tarragona",
    44: "Teruel",
    45: "Toledo",
    46: "Valencia",
    47: "Valladolid",
    48: "Vizcaya",
    49: "Zamora",
    50: "Zaragoza",
    51: "Ceuta",
    52: "Melilla"
  };

  if (cpostal.length == 5 && (cpostal <= 52999 && cpostal >= 1000)) {
    document.getElementById('provincia').innerHTML = cp_provincias[parseInt(cpostal.substring(0, 2))];
    document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = false; 
  } else {
    codigopostal.value = "";
    document.getElementById('provincia').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("enviar").disabled = true; 
    alert("¡Código postal incorrecto!");
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  ¿En que código postal resides?
  <input type="text" id="codigopostal" value="" required />
  <p id="provincia"></p>
  <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar" disabled>
</form>
```